# SOMessaging BalloonImage is missing when cell message contain Media

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using SOMessagging in my app and its behaving very inconsistent when images and text is showing in same thread. Some times ballonImage is not shown in text as seen in pics. Its clearly seen that text and balloonImage both are not shown but they both exist there and options are appear. Tell me how could i handle it, thanks in advance.

[image]

[image][image]

[image]

And here is the code snippets

```
- (void)configureMessageCell:(SOMessageCell *)cell forMessageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    Message *message = self.dataSource[index];

// Adjusting content for 3pt. (In this demo the width of    bubble's tail is 6pt)
    if (!message.fromMe) {
        cell.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 3.0f, 0, 0); //Move content for 3 pt. to right
        cell.textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [cell.textView setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        cell.balloonImage = [self balloonImageForReceiving];
    } else {
        cell.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 3.0f); //Move content for 3 pt. to left
        cell.textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [cell.textView setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        cell.balloonImage = [self balloonImageForSending];
    }

// Fix user image position on top or bottom.
    cell.userImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.userImageSize.width / 2;
    cell.userImageView.autoresizingMask = message.fromMe? UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin : UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

    if (message.media) {
        cell.mediaImageView.tag = index;
        UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(buttonWithImageOnScreenPressed:)];
        [cell.mediaImageView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
    }
}

- (UIImage *)balloonImageForReceiving
{
    UIImage *bubble = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bubbleReceive.png"];
    UIColor *color = [UIColor grayColor];
    bubble = [self tintImage:bubble withColor:color];
    return [bubble resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(17, 27, 21, 17)];
}

- (UIImage *)balloonImageForSending
{
    UIImage *bubble = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bubble.png"];
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:12/255.0 green:136/255.0 blue:207/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    bubble = [self tintImage:bubble withColor:color];
    return [bubble resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(17, 21, 16, 27)];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution, here is the detail

There is a method **setMessage** in **SOMessageCell.m** i mistakenly commit the line **[self setInitialSizes]** after un-commiting it my issue is solved, check may be this can help you out too.

```
(void)setMessage:(SOMessage *)message
{
    _message = message;

   [self setInitialSizes];
   [self adjustCell];
}
```